# PowerShell command to parameterised PowerShell function?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm not so hot with PowerShell yet, but have managed to get this command to work quite nicely:

```
get-childitem "C:\Code\WC1" -Recurse | select-string "insert into\s+my_table"
```

Thing is, I know I'm going to struggle to remember this, so how can I make it into a function where the path supplied to `get-childitem` and the search regex are parameters?

I'm using PowerShell 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function Find-Code([string] $path, [string] $pattern)
{
    get-childitem $path -Recurse | select-string $pattern
}
```

You can put this in your [PowerShell Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(VS.85).aspx).
An easy way to do this is to edit the `$profile` file (run something like `notepad $profile` from your PowerShell prompt) and just paste the text right in.

Comment: +1 for your answer, an I'll accept it too if you can tell me where I put it so that it's always available in a new PS session...

Comment: My pleasure. I'm glad you found my answer useful.

Answer (score 2):

more commonly these days the parameters are being called after the function declaration e.g.

```
Function Find-Code {
    param([string] $path, [string] $pattern)
    get-childitem $path -Recurse | select-string $pattern
}
```